# Jest error, Requires Babel “^7.0.0-0”, but was loaded with “6.26.3”

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, babeljs, babel-core

I get this error for every Jest test suite I run:

`Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.`

But what is strange, this error appears only if I try to install packages via `npm install`. So what is the problem? What I do wrong?
P.S. I don't want to use `yarn install`.

Here is my `paskage.json`s babel, jest and enzyme related parts:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-docgen": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
  },
}
```

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Jest 23 does not support @babel/core 7. Either upgrade to Jest 24 which supports babel 7 or run

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0
```

to load a compatible version of babel for jest 23